# Wake on Lan has suddenly stopped working

Tags: networking, windows-10, wake-on-lan

Wake on Lan has suddenly stopped working, after a few weeks.

I:
- Enabled the option in the BIOS
- Prevented adapter from saving power
- Enabled delivery of magic packet in device manager
- Configured a static ip
- Port - forwarding

I know my public ip changed, could this be the cause of the problem?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 64bit

Comment: WOL doesn't seem to be very reliable -- See https://superuser.com/questions/556303/how-reliable-is-wake-on-lan-if-configured-correctly

Answer (score 1):

Please know that it's not related to IP changes. At Layer 2, (the Data Link layer) WOL uses MAC (Media Access Control) addresses to turn on a specific PC. The MAC address is critical, as a PC in the off condition doesn't have an IP address.

Besides this, if there is any other changes like install some updates including Windows or drivers, you can try to rollback and see if it works for you.

Then, check power option to see if the Fast startup is turned on, if so, turn off it.

Check Wake on Magic Packet under network adapter properties has been configured to enabled: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if **ethernet led is on** when you shutdown the PC.

If it is not then -

1. Update network adapter driver
2. Right Click This PC > Manage > Device Manager >Network Adapters > Double Clicked on motherboard network adapter > Advanced tab > Enable **Shutdown Wake ON LAN**

Check if ethernet led is on when you shutdown the PC.

Hopefully, it will be turned on now and you will be good to go.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: WOL has multiple settings. It can be on OS and/or BIOS. This is just one of the settings which could help in different scenarios. But it is very hard to find. At least the forums I went through, did not emphasize enough on this setting. After hours of research & trial and error, this solution worked for me. These questions did not seem duplicate to me. But the answers are duplicate. I benefit from other peoples knowledge so I thought I should share my findings, in case it help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall
Private networks should be "connected". If Guest of public networks shows as connected, change to Private.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).